# Return results from one of two tables, based on max sum of costs

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have two tables with costs.  One set is what was actually recorded, and one is estimates based on the brand

What I want to do is report on whichever is higher.

Sample data is:

ParentTable:

`GroupId, TransactionId, Otherinfo..... 
   123,       4444,    ...
   530,       2311,    ...
   201,       1111,    ...`

ActualData

`TransactionId, Product, Cost
  4444,          3039,     100
  4444,          3002,     4000
  2311,          3004,     693`

EstimateData

`GroupId, Brand, Cost
   123,     33,    80
   123,     42,    3000
   530,     222,   1200
   201,     121,   4040`

In this situation, what I want to return is a table that contains

`GroupId,  Code,  Cost 
   123,    3039,  100      <- Actual data
   123,    3002,  4000     <- Actual data
   530,    222,   1200     <- Estimate data
   201,    121,   4040     <- Estimate data`

Currently I am looking at first doing a select from both tables, returning GroupId with Max(cost).  I'm struggling on how to use this to return the results I want.

Can anyone help me?

*EDIT*  Added in the parent table.. It doesn't really change things, but might give more insight as to the data

Comment: Your data structure doesn't make sense.  How are the actual and estimates tables connected?  (That is, how do you know the brand for a given product?)  What is `code` in your output?

Comment: The link is by GroupId.  It's quite fuzzy, I agree.  Basically we have situations where there is no data recorded, so we have another table that has estimates to make up for the lack of actual data.  In the final table the Code column is either the Brand or the Product, depending on which table is used for the data

Comment: Why is `123,3039,100` in your table of desired results? i'm guessing it's because the cost is higher than 80 (1st row in EstimatedData) - but how do you determine that's the row you need to compare it to?

Comment: Or should `(123, 33)` and `(123, 42)` also be present in the output table and are simply missing in the example output?

Comment: Because the sum of GroupId 123 is greater in the actual data.  TransactionId 4444 = 4100 total, whereas the Estimate for GroupId 123 is only 3080, thus I want the Acutal data in this case.  The reverse is true for GroupId 530, where the Estimate total is higher, thus I want the Estimate result.  And GroupId 201 doesn't have any actual data, so I use the estimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to select every row of a group from the table where its total is the largest. The cte contains all groupId's and which table the largest total comes from. The union then uses the cte to only select rows belonging to the largest groups for each table.

```
with cte as (
    select * from (
        select source, GroupId,
        row_number() over (partition by GroupId order by total_cost desc) rn
        from (
            select 'ad' source, GroupId, sum(Cost) total_cost
            from ActualData ad
            group by GroupId
            union all
            select 'ed' source, GroupId, sum(Cost) total_cost
            from EstimatedData ed
            group by GroupId
        ) t1
    ) t1 where rn = 1
)

select GroupId, Product Code, Cost from ActualData ad
where GroupId in (select GroupId from cte where source = 'ad')
union all
select GroupId, Brand Code, Cost from EstimatedData ed
where GroupId in (select GroupId from cte where source = 'ed')
```

Comment: The union inside the CTE should be `UNION ALL` the use of literals as 'source' removes any ability to reduce the number of rows so `UNION` by itself is a waste.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship is definitely fuzzy however the expected result

```
| GROUPID | CODE | COST |
|---------|------|------|
|     123 | 3039 |  100 |
|     123 | 3002 | 4000 |
|     201 |  121 | 4040 |
|     530 |  222 | 1200 |
```

was produced by this query:

```
WITH
    acte AS (
                  SELECT p.GroupId, ad.Product, ad.Cost
                       , SUM(ad.cost) OVER (PARTITION BY Groupid) AS grp_cost
                  FROM ActualData AS ad
                        INNER JOIN parenttable p ON ad.TransactionId = p.TransactionId
            ),
   ecte AS (
                  SELECT GroupId, Brand, SUM(Cost) AS cost
                  FROM EstimateData
                  GROUP BY
                        GroupId
                      , Brand
            )
SELECT acte.GroupId, acte.Product AS Code, acte.Cost
FROM acte
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                  NULL
            FROM ecte
            WHERE ecte.GroupId = acte.GroupId
                  AND ecte.cost > acte.grp_cost
      )
UNION ALL
      SELECT ecte.GroupId, ecte.Brand AS Code, ecte.Cost
      FROM ecte
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT
                        NULL
                  FROM acte
                  WHERE acte.GroupId = ecte.GroupId
                        AND acte.grp_cost > ecte.cost
            )
;
```

<kbd>[See this SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af798d/9)</kbd>